# Given $A A^T A = A$ and $B B^T B = B$, can we get $A^T A B B^T = B B^T A^T A$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Given two matrices $A,B$ with real entries and with the property in the title, can we prove $A^T A B B^T = B B^T A^T A$? The matrices need not be invertible.

Comment: Why would you think that $A^TA$ can commute with $BB^T$ if $A$ and $B$ are completely unrelated in the given conditions?

Comment: Do we have that A, B are invertible?

Comment: They are not necessarily invertible

Comment: For such questions, one should first try an example with $2\times 2$-matrices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a counter example:
$$
A=\pmatrix{1 & 0 \cr 0 & 0},
$$
and
$$
B=\pmatrix{1/2 & 1/2 \cr 1/2 & 1/2}.
$$

Comment: Indeed, $[AA^T,BB^T]=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1/2\cr -1/2 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: Thanks! this is what I needed

Answer (score 1):

I will provide a different perspective. The proposition holds if

#### At least one of $A, B$ is invertible.

To see this, multiply $A^{-1}$ to the first equation: $$A ^{-1}(AA^TA)=A ^{-1}A \implies IA^TA=I$$ where I is the $3\times 3$ identity matrix. Therefore $A^TA=I$. Thus, $$A ^T ABB ^T=IBB ^T=BB ^T=BB ^TI=BB ^TA ^TA.$$

---

You could also have done this by writing $\displaystyle BB ^TB=B\implies B^{-1}BB ^TB=B^{-1}B$.